# DISTINCT fields NOT to show up in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm running the feeds Table where I don't want DISTINCT fields with "NULL" to retrieve.

```
$this->Feed->recursive = 0;
$this->paginate = array('Feed' => array(
'limit' => 6, 
'fields' => 'DISTINCT Feed.* IS NOT NULL',
'conditions' => array('Feed.member_id' => $friends_ids), 
'order' => array('Feed.created' => 'DESC'), 
));
$notes = $this->paginate('Feed');
$this->set('notes', $notes);

// debug($notes);
unset($notes);
```

This gives me an error. Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Feed.* IS NOT NULL'. Running this on cakephp 1.3 Thanks.

Comment: should it be a condition instead of fields?

Comment: BTW: When You use DISTINCT with pagination, the count() return incorrect values, see: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8778

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the NULL check to the conditions array.

```
'fields' => 'DISTINCT Feed.*',
'conditions' => array(
    'Feed.member_id' => $friends_ids,
    'Feed.the_field_to_check IS NOT NULL'
),
```